# MySQL get items with specific attributes ordered by number of attributes contained

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables:
food-

```
id    name
1     pizza
2     pasta
3     salad
```

tags

```
id    tagName
1     spicy
2     non-spicy
3     healthy
4     cheesy
```

food_tag

```
id    food_id    tag_id
1     1          1
2     1          4
3     2          2
4     2          4
5     3          3
6     3          2
```

I want to query these three tables to get the food items ordered by maximum number of matching tags. So if I query for foods with tags ('spicy', 'cheesy'), I should get Pizza and Pasta in that order, but not Salad (because it doesn't contain any relevant tags).

I am trying this query, which is not giving me the results I want:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT c.tagName) FROM food a, tags b, food_tag c
 WHERE b.tagName in ('spicy', 'cheesy') AND b.id = c.tag_id 
 AND a.id = c.food_id ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT c.tagName) DESC;
```

My desired output is:

```
a.name   count(distinct c.tagName)  
pizza    2
pasta    1
```

Can anybody tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: See aggregate functions. Your error is an omission. And use explicit join syntax

Comment: I dont really know about this syntax... Can you help me with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**issue**

> - missing group by a.name

**adjusted query**

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagName) 
FROM food a, tags b, food_tag c 
WHERE b.tagName in ('spicy', 'cheesy') 
AND b.id = c.tag_id 
AND a.id = c.food_id 
group by a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagName) DESC
;
```

**output**

```
+-------+---------------------------+
| name  | COUNT(DISTINCT b.tagName) |
+-------+---------------------------+
| pizza |                         2 |
| pasta |                         1 |
+-------+---------------------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b3f/3)

Comment: group by is indeed nice. interesting thing about this is most other dbms would throw an error if the user doesnt specify group by